# How to query in grafana dynamically for prometheus scrape configs?

Tags: prometheus, grafana, prometheus-node-exporter

The [provided grafana dashboard](https://github.com/rfrail3/grafana-dashboards/blob/master/prometheus/node-exporter-full.json) for node-exporter automatically retrieves the node-exporter scrape configs vor the variable job by this query: `label_values(node_uname_info, job)`.

Is it possible to query for job variable values for my own prometheus scrape configs (for example by a pattern like `prom-scrape-*`)?

At the moment I'm using prometheus and grafana with docker. A kubernetes solution would be also nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You configure a query in the grafana variable configuration which will return the required values.
2. You extract the value by a regular expression.

This example will extract all solr prometheus scrape jobs:

[image: Variable Configuration]

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if this helps

Step 1 - Add Prometheus scraping in your code for different metrics
Step 2 - Verify that the metrics can be seen from Prometheus
Step 3 - Create a new dashboard and write your own query. Choose Prometheus from the dropdown.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktJ4v.png)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sorry, my question was not clear enough. I wanted to ask for the query in the variable configuration. Meanwhile I found the solution myself (see my own answer).